# Angular JS Bound HTML Functions Not Recognized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an app that draws data and displays it in the form of a table.  Angular JS is used for sorting and pagination.  The pagination div I have is injected using a function in Angular that builds a string a sets it to the $scope.pagination variable.  The problem is that the ng-click functions within the injected HTML are not recognized when they are clicked.  I'm assuming it is due to the fact that they are not there when the page is rendered.

```
<html ng-app="listingsApp">   
<body ng-controller="pageController" ng-init="type=0">
<div class="pagination" ng-bind-html="paginate"></div>

  var listingsApp = angular.module('listingsApp', []);

  listingsApp.controller('pageController', function($scope, $sce, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.BuildPaginationHtml = function(showPage) {
      pageString = "<span class=\"paginationItem \" ng-click=\"GoToPage(" + i + ")\"> " + i + " </span>";
      $scope.pagination = pageString;
    }
  }
```

Here clicking the span does not go to the GoToPage function.  I have a console log to verify it.  All the other click events on the page work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic HTML, you have to use `$compile`

```
listingsApp.controller('pageController', function ($scope, $sce, $filter, $http, $compile) {
    $scope.BuildPaginationHtml = function(showPage) {
        pageString = $compile("<span class=\"paginationItem \" ng-click=\"GoToPage(" + i + ")\"> " + i + " </span>")($scope);
        $scope.pagination = pageString;
    }
});
```